# JPA / JPQL data list injection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get somthing like this in JPA:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Entity e 
WHERE e.values IN (:values)
```

Resulting in the execution of this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE 
WHERE VALUES IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list as a parameter, this is an example to show how to set the parameter in the query:

```
        TypedQuery<Entity> query = em.createQuery("select e from Entity e where e.value IN :values", Entity.class);
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
        query.setParameter("values", list);
        List<Entity> results = query.getResultList();
```